# Implement conditional reduction of two lists into a single list containing two elements using Stream API

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

I'm comparing two *lists* based on the following conditions:

1. If *list1* has higher value, `+1` to the first element in the result.
2. If *list2* has higher value, `+1` to the second element in the result.
3. If values are the same, skip it.

I have implemented this solution in Java 7

```
int min = a.size() > b.size() ? b.size() : a.size();
List<Integer> result = Arrays.asList(0, 0);
for(int i =0;  i < min; i++) {
    if(a.get(i) > b.get(i)) 
        result.set(0, result.get(0) + 1);
    else if(a.get(i) < b.get(i))
        result.set(1, result.get(1) + 1);
}

return result;
```

How could I do the same with Java 8 streams?

I came up with two streams and merging the results of both. Because I am not sure how to do both the conditions in single streams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `range()` method of the `IntStream` we can create a stream of indices that are valid for these lists.

To filter out indices for which values are not equal, we can apply  `filter()` operation.

Accumulating the result in a list comprised of two elements will require a bit more effort. For that we can use [`collect(supplier,accumulator,combiner)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BiConsumer)):

- *supplier* - a function that returns a new *mutable container*. Here we need to provide a *list* that should hold the results of reduction;
- *accumulator* - is a function defines the logic on how to add stream elements into the *container*;
- *combiner* - a function that defines how to merge the two containers with partial results obtained while executing the stream in parallel.

```
List<Integer> a = List.of(1, 2, 5);
List<Integer> b = List.of(1, 2, 8);
    
List<Integer> result = IntStream.range(0, Math.min(a.size(), b.size()))
    .filter(i -> a.get(i) != b.get(i)) // filter out non-equal elements
    .collect(
        () -> Arrays.asList(0, 0), // supplier - provides a container which contain the results of reduction
        (list, i) -> {             // combiner - defines the logic on the container should be updated
            if (a.get(i) > b.get(i)) list.set(0, list.get(0) + 1);
            else list.set(1, list.get(1) + 1);
        },
        (left, right) -> {         // accumulator - provides the logic for merging the two containers while executing in parallel
            left.set(0, left.get(0) + right.get(0));
            left.set(1, left.get(1) + right.get(1));
        }
    );

System.out.println(result);
```

*Output:*

```
[0, 1]
```

In case you doubt where it's a correct way to approach this problem with streams, have a look at the API documentation, paragraph [*Mutable reduction*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction).

And even if after getting familiar with the reference above, you might think that it can be done without `collect()`. For instance, why don't we simply apply `filter().forEach()` to make the code leaner? Then have a look at another part of the API documentation, which is dedicated to [*Side-effects*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#SideEffects).

Comment: @Gibbs That's because the way of reduction isn't very straightforward. In general, Streams are not the most suitable tool when have a complicated conditional logic. In production it's better to implement similar task using plain loops.

Comment: What are two containers?

Comment: @Gibbs Container is a *mutable* object that is used to accumulate the results of reduction. If you are executing stream in parallel (for that you need to apply `parallel()`) stream data would be divided into chunks and executed in different threads. Then results produced by each thread needs to be merged. That is a general mechanism.

Comment: @Gibbs We can also use in parallel a concurrent *Collector* (for instance built-in collector [`toMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toConcurrentMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator,java.util.function.Supplier)) is a parallel collector, i.e. its optimized for parallel execution). It doesn't create a new instance of the container for every thread, instead each thread updates the same container (for instance a concurrent collection).